Writing the $sin$ $cos$ power sum as a sum of multiple angles.
Writing the $sin$ $cos$ power sum as a sum of multiple angles.
Trying to answer the se question, which did not specify the multiple angle solutions, I started to look for a generalization and arrived at the following equations depending on even or odd values of $n$:
\begin{align} 
\cos^n x +\sin^n x & = 2^{2-n} \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{4}}{\frac{1}{2^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{1+k}\right\rfloor}}\dbinom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+2 k} \cos (4 k x)} \;& \forall \; n\equiv 0\mod 2\\
\cos^n x + \sin^n x & = 2^{1-n} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n+1}{2}}{\binom{n}{\frac{n+1}{2}-k} \left( \cos ((2k-1)x)-(-1)^k\sin((2k-1)x)\right)} \; & \forall \; n\equiv 1\mod 2 
\end{align}
Question 1: Can the first equation for even $n$ be written without the characteristic function$\lfloor .. \rfloor$?
Question 2: Or better , can both equations be combined into one? (There can be only one)
For $n=4,6$ we see that we get two multiple angle formulae for $\cos(4x)$ :
$$\cos (4 x)=4 \left(\sin ^4x+\cos ^4x\right)-3=\frac{1}{6} \left(16 \left(\sin ^6x+\cos ^6x\right)-10\right) $$
Question 3: Are there other multiple angle formulae for which sums of powers exist?
There are many Multiple-Angle formulae listed at wiki identities and Wolfram Multiple-Angle but no sums of powers as far as I could see.
Question 4: Can you recommend any references to this subject?

This is unreal after only 2 min down voted without a comment.

What does $\sum_{a_m,k}$ mean to you? As written, all the sin functions cancel out.

The first general sum is a representation wihout further meaning. Cancellation depends on the value of k. Look at the 3rd equation sin does not cancel out.

The $\sum_{a_m,k}$ term doesn't make any sense. What are the $a_m$? Is it a double sum with two indices or are you summing over two distinct sets?

Ok I take it that it is confusing ,so I removed it. To me it was just a general representation $a_m$ being some coefficients. Only one sum as you can see for the other equations.

@Thomas  for clarity I removed it. But thank you for your kind input.

I would break out the $k=0$ term in the even case, and just make it $\binom n{n/2}+\sum_{k=1}^n.$ No reason to handle all terms the same. $2^{\lfloor 1/(k+1)\rfloor}$ is way too confusing.

@Thomas Thank you so taking $\binom{n}{n/2}/2$ as a fixed term I can remove the $\lfloor..\rfloor$ from the equation for even $n$. Good answer for Question 1 :-)

The explanation for the $\cos(4x)$ part is simpler.
Let $A_{n}(x)=\cos^{2n}(x)+\sin^{2n}(x).$
This satisfies $A_0(x)=2, A_1(x)=1,$ and $$ \begin{align} 
A_{n+1}(x)&=(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))A_n(x)-\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)A_{n-1}(x)\\&=A_n(x)-\frac14\sin^2(2x)A_{n-1}(x)\\&=A_n(x)+\frac18(\cos(4x)-1)A_{n-1}(x). \end{align}  $$
So what you really get is $A_n(x)$ is always a polynomial of $\cos(4x),$ with $A_2,A_3$ linear in $\cos(4x)$ because $A_0$ and $A_1$ are constants.

The above uses a rule about sequences $c_n=ar_1^n+br_2^n,$ that $$c_{n+1}=(r_1+r_2)c_n-(r_1r_2)c_{n-1}.$$
In our case, $a=b=1,$ $r_1=\cos^2x, r_2=\sin^2 x.$

If you write the polyn9mial as polynomials $p_n(y)$ such that $p_n\left(\frac{\cos(4x)-1}8\right)=A_n(x),$ you get $$p_0(y)=2, p_1(y)=1, p_{n+1}(y)=p_n+yp_{n-1}(y)$$
So $$ \begin{align}  p_2(y)&=1+2y,\\p_3(y)&=1+3y,\\
p_4(y)&=1+4y+2y^2,\\
p_5(y)&=1+5y+5y^2
\end{align} $$
This lets us solve for $\cos(4x)$ in terms of a quadratic formula involving $A_4(x)$ or $A_5(x).$ For example,
$$\cos(4x)=-7\pm4\sqrt{2+2(\cos^8x+\sin^8x)}$$ or something like that. Obviously, it is only true for on of the $\pm$ signs. If that formula is correct, the $+$ sign is requires to bring the value in the range $[-1,1].$

If you define $B_n(x)=\frac{\cos^{2n+1}(x)+\sin^{2n+1}(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}$ you get that $B_0(x)=1$ and $B_{-1}(x)=\frac2{\sin(2x)}$ and the recursion: $$B_{n+1}(x)=B_n(x)-\frac{\sin^2(2x)}4 B_{n-1}(x),$$ which makes, for $n\geq 0,$ $B_n(x)$ is a polynomial of $\sin(2x).$
If we let $y=\sin(2x)/2,$ then $q_0(y)=1, q_1(y)=1-y,$ and $$q_{n+1}(y)=q_n(y)-y^2q_{n-1}(y).$$

Ok this is a nice recurrence for $n$ even. Now your $n$'s are iterations and have to be multiplied by 2 to obtain the power $n$ from the sum for even powers.

The same recurrence works for the odd cases, $B_n(x)=\cos^{2n+1}(x)+\sin^{2n+1}(x),$ but you don't get constants for $B_0,B_1,$ so it is less helpful.

"Now your $n$s are iterations..." What does that comment mean? @Jakob

Thank you Thomas I like the solutions for the quadratic $A_4(x)$ for $A_5(x)$ I verified $\cos(4 x) = \frac{1}{5}\left(-15 + 4 \sqrt{5 + 20 \left(\cos^{10}(x) + \sin^{10}(x)\right)}\right) $ looks like a good answer for Question 3

Well the iterator for your recurrence is $\frac{n}{2}$ ($n$ being the degree) due to the quadratic of $A_n(x)$

I just realized that we can easily set $A_n(x)$ has period $\pi/2,$ and is even, so we get that the Fourier coefficients must be non-zero only for the terms $\cos(4kx),$ and this also lets us deduce that $A_n(x)$ is always a polynomial of $\cos(4x).$
